# How to mock third party library using jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs, rollbar

I am developing a `node.js` application using `nestjs`
I have a class called `LoggerService` as below

```
export class LoggerService {

    private logger: Rollbar;

    constructor() {
        this.logger = this.setupLogger();
    }

    critical(...args: Array<string | Error | object | Date | any[]>) {
        this.logger.error(...args);
    }

    private setupLogger(): Rollbar {
        if (this.logger == null) {

            this.logger = new Rollbar({
                accessToken: 'token',
                environment: 'dev',
                captureUncaught: true,
                captureUnhandledRejections: true,
            });

        }

        return this.logger;
    }
```

Now I am writing unit test for this class using jest as below.

```
describe('LoggerService.log', () => {
  let service: LoggerService;

  beforeEach(async () => {

    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [LoggerService],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<LoggerService>(LoggerService);
  });

  it('critical', () => {
    service.critical('error','message');
    expect(???).toHaveBeenCalledWith('error', 'message')
  })

);
```

My question is how to check(expect) if `logger.error` is called, or how to mock `Rollbar` in this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Provide your external dependency/library as an injectable token in your module

```
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'Rollbar',
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => new Rollbar({
                accessToken: configService.accessToken,
                environment: configService.environment,
                captureUncaught: true,
                captureUnhandledRejections: true,
            }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    },
  ]
```

2) Inject it in your `LoggerService` instead of creating it

```
export class LoggerService {
    constructor(@Inject('Rollbar') private logger: Rollbar) {
    }
```

3) Now you can mock your dependency in your test

```
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  providers: [
    LoggerService,
    { provide: 'Rollbar', useFactory: rollbarMockFactory },
  ],
}).compile();
```

Comment: Awesome, just one thing where is `rollbarMockFactory` defined?

Comment: Glad you find it helpful. :-) That's just a placeholder. If you want to learn more about mocking, have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55366343/4694994

Comment: I did that, and in my test my code is like `const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        LoggerService,
        {
          provide: 'Rollbar', useFactory: jest.fn(() => ({
            error: jest.fn(() => null),
          }))
        }
      ],
    })` but I get this error ` Nest can't resolve dependencies of the LoggerService (?). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the _RootTestModule context` 
and this is my service `constructor(@Inject('Rollbar') private logger: Rollbar) {  }`

Comment: Does the server start up? Btw: You should not use a plain string as a token in production. Define a constant for your injection token. Definitely make sure that your tokens are the same everywhere.

Comment: also I did this, still same `      .overrideProvider('Rollbar')
      .useFactory({
        factory: () => ({
          error: jest.fn(() => null),
        })
      })
`

Comment: and also this one `      providers: [
        LoggerService,
        {
          provide: 'Rollbar',
          useValue: {
            error: jest.fn(() => null),
          }
        }
      ],
`

Comment: Mh, I don't know why it doesn't work for you, it does for in my code. :-| Maybe has something to do with https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/412#issuecomment-366076180 ?

Comment: There are also a couple of bugs linked to injection tokens. Maybe try updating your dependencies: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/2379

Comment: I am on '6.5.3' which is the latest ;)

Comment: I submitted a bug in their repo, https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/2713

Comment: btw I mark your response as answer, since it's right direction

Comment: As a workaround, you can just create the service manually in your test with `new LoggerService(rollbarMock)`. You don't need the TestingModule utitlities in a unit test, see https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1786#issuecomment-475585609

Comment: It was my mistake , I have had 2 `describe` and I changed 1 and error was from the second one ;DDDD

Comment: Also would you please take a look at this question as well
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57383233/how-to-create-custom-provider-for-third-party-library-in-nestjs-with-access-to-r