# How to create custom provider for third-party library in nestjs with access to request and response

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, nestjs

I have a controller in `nestjs` as below

```
import * as dialogflow from 'dialogflow-fulfillment';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

@Controller('dialogflow-fulfillment')
export class DialogflowFulfillmentController {

    @Post()
    async fulfill(@Req() request: Request, @Res() response: Response) {

        const agent = new dialogflow.WebhookClient({ request, response });

    }
}
```

Now for being able to unit test this controller I want to use custom provider and provide an instance of WebhookClient.

Something like below

```
    {
      provide: 'WebhookService',
      useFactory: async () => new dialogflow.WebhookClient({??,??})
    }
```

but problem is I need to get access to instance of `request` and `response` to create a new instance.

How can I do that? And how to inject it in each calls of `fulfill`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I'd suggest to write a facade (wrapper) around the library. The facade does not need to be unit tested since it simply propagates the parameters and does not contain logic (you could write a "facade test" instead which essentially tests the library code, I'd say an integration test is a better fit):

```
@Injectable()
export class WebHookClientFacade {
  create(request, response) {
    return new dialogflow.WebhookClient({ request, response });
  }
}
```

And use the facade in your controller that is now testable:

```
constructor(private webHookClientBuilder: WebHookClientFacade) {}

@Post()
async fulfill(@Req() request: Request, @Res() response: Response) {
    const agent = this.webHookClientBuilder.create(request, response);

}
```