# How to mock function from library in javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, sinon

I have code that imports library easysoap to get a request from WSDL. And I'm trying to refactor my unit test.

I've written the unit test with jest and  mock the return value but it's called the true endpoint

my function requestConverter.helper.ts

```js
import * as EasySoap from 'easysoap';
export async function requestConverter(params, method, body) {
  const opts = {
    secure: false
  };
  const easySoap = await EasySoap(params, opts);
  try {
    const result = easySoap.call({
      method,
      params: body
    });
    return result[`data`];
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
}
```

my test file

```js
import { requestConverter } from '../helpers/requestConverter.helper';
import * as EasySoap from 'easysoap';

describe('covert http request to wsdl request', () => {
  let params: object;
  let method: string;
  let body: object;
  let expectedResponse: object;
  let opts: object;
  beforeEach(() => {
    params = {
      host: '223.27.147.38',
      path: '/~kabgianyar/ppobwebservice/develop/webservice-pdam/CustomerBillingPelInfo3Tagihan.php',
      wsdl: '/~kabgianyar/ppobwebservice/develop/webservice-pdam/CustomerBillingPelInfo3Tagihan.php?wsdl'
    };
    method = 'billinfo';
    body = {
      namapengguna: 'value',
      katasandi: 'abs'
    };
    expectedResponse = {
      billinfoResponse: {
        'xmlns:ns1': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
        "return": 'mocked'
      }
    };
    opts = {
      secure: false
    };
  });
  afterEach(() => jest.restoreAllMocks());
  it('should return response from wsdl', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(EasySoap, 'call').mockImplementation(jest.fn().mockReturnValue(expectedResponse));
    const result = await requestConverter(params, method, body);
    expect(EasySoap.call).toBeCalled();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result), '====');
  });
});
```

I want the response to be

```js
expectedResponse = {
  billinfoResponse: {
    'xmlns:ns1': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
    "return": 'mocked'
  }
};
```

Comment: Have a look at these two threads: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57393748/4694994 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/57381798/4694994

Comment: it's not what i'm looking for

Comment: In your code you're not using nest.js at all. Of course, that's an option but if you want to actually use nestjs then you should use the dependency injection system to mock your dependencies as described in those two threads. Otherwise you should remove nest.js from the tags.

Comment: What solution do you need? jestjs or sinon?