# NestJS service testing: try to test a simple save

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I have this particular error: "TypeError: this.commentRepository.save is not a function"

When I run this simple test:

```js
describe('CommentService', () => {
    let commentService: CommentService;

    const mockCommentRepository = {
        createComment: jest.fn(comment => comment),
    };

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                CommentService,
                {
                    provide: getRepositoryToken(Comment),
                    useValue: mockCommentRepository,
                }
            ],
        }).compile();

        commentService = module.get<CommentService>(CommentService);
    });

    it('should create a comment', async () => {
        expect(await commentService.createComment({ message: 'test message'})).toEqual({
            id: expect.any(Number),
            message: 'test message',
        });
    });
});
```

The service:

```js
  async createComment(comment: Partial<Comment>): Promise<Comment> {
    return await this.commentRepository.save(comment);
  }
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Your `mockCommentRepository` does not have `save()` method you are calling in your service `createComment` method. Mock this method as well to get rid of the error.
Also refer to this answer for more info on repository mocking https://stackoverflow.com/a/55366343/5716745

Comment: const mockCommentRepository = {
        createComment: jest.fn(comment => comment),
        save: jest.fn((comment) => comment),
    };

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to create a provider for the Repository you have to mock the repository methods (in this case the save function).

```
{
  provide: getRepositoryToken(Comment),
  useValue: {
    save: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(null),
  },
},
```