# How can I Mock Mongoose Query.prototype.exec() method with Jest?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I am writing unit test cases for a service (built with NestJs) that fetches data with mongoose, nestjs/mongoose packages.

I have simple async method that looks like this (following nestjs's [documention found here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb)):

```
async getMyObjectById(id: string): Promise<MyObject> {
     return await this.model.findById(id).exec();
}
```

This functioning as expected. I have a basic configuration with mocks for [mongoose Queries as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55143467/testing-mongoose-models-with-nestjs#:%7E:text=38-,I%20know,-this%20post%20is):

My test looks like this:

```
test('find one item by id', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(myMockModel, 'findById').mockResolvedValueOnce('return something');
    const result = await myService.getMyObjectById('1234556');
    expect(result['_id']).toBe('1234556');
});
```

I get an error related to the `.exec()` method:

```
TypeError: this.model.findById(...).exec is not a function
```

I am able to run this service in dev mode + retrieve information from mongodb, etc. Solutions works just fine. If I remove the `.exec()` method, mocks works as well. But on the exec() method I am get an undefined. Also tried mocking mongoose Query prototype viz:

```
jest.spyOn(myMockModel, 'findById').mockResolvedValueOnce(new Query<MyObject, any>());
jest.spyOn(Query.prototype, 'exec').mockResolvedValue('desired value');
```

and other similar alternatives, but the outcome is the same. Just for the [recommendation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#should-you-use-exec-with-await), I'd like to keep the .exec() method.

Answer (score 1):

Based on documentation from jest ([Here](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#:%7E:text=call%27%2C%20%27default%27%2C%20%27default%27-,For%20cases,-where%20we%20have)) use jest.fn().mockReturnThis() is preferred for chaining. I was able to use `.mockReturnValue` to create an object with the `.exec` method. Solution looks like this:

```
test('find one item by id', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(myMockModel, 'findById').mockReturnThis()
    .mockReturnValue({
        exec: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce('return something'),
    } as unknown as Query<MyObject, any>);
    const result = await myService.getMyObjectById('1234556');
    expect(result['_id']).toBe('1234556');
});
```